# Multiple if statements with GET not outputting correctly in PHP with XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the total times two authors have edited or coauthored books. (They are selected by a user using checkboxes, so I've used GET to see if the checkbox is selected).

I am cross referencing the authors 'a' (mj) and 'b' (ms) from 'a's' (mj) xml doc that features all their publishing information.

Currently I have this:

```
if ($_GET['author'] == 'mj55'){

                $getMj = new DOMDocument();
                $getMj->load("Margret-Jane.xml");
                $mjxpath = new DOMXpath($getMj);

                $mjAuth = $mjxpath->query("////author[@id = 'mj55']")->length;
                $mjEdit = $mjxpath->query("////editor[@id = 'mj55']")->length;
                $mjResult = ($mjAuth + $mjEdit);




                if ($_GET['author'] == 'ms10' ) {

                    $mjmsA = $mjxpath->query("////author[@id = 'ms10']")->length;
                    $mjmsE = $mjxpath->query("////editor[@id = 'ms10']")->length;
                    $mjmsTotal = ($mjmsA + $mjmsE);
                    echo $mjmsTotal;
                }
            }
```

if I put an echo $mjResult at the end of the first if statement, I get the correct output. But I don't get any output at all from the echo $mjmsTotal

Comment: Should the second `if` be inside the first `if`? If `$_GET['author']` is `'mj55'`, how can the second `if` be true? It never gets hit.

Comment: how would I be able to make it so that both conditions are checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used a nested if and that's why you are getting a result of only first if.. try to use both the if statement totally independent with each other. Here is an example-

```
$getMj = new DOMDocument();
$getMj->load("Margret-Jane.xml");
$mjxpath = new DOMXpath($getMj);
if ($_GET['author'] == 'mj55'){
                $mjAuth = $mjxpath->query("////author[@id = 'mj55']")->length;
                $mjEdit = $mjxpath->query("////editor[@id = 'mj55']")->length;
                $mjResult = ($mjAuth + $mjEdit);
            }
 if ($_GET['author'] == 'ms10' ) {
                    $mjmsA = $mjxpath->query("////author[@id = 'ms10']")->length;
                    $mjmsE = $mjxpath->query("////editor[@id = 'ms10']")->length;
                    $mjmsTotal = ($mjmsA + $mjmsE);
                    echo $mjmsTotal;
                }
```

Comment: If you only go into the second `if`,  all of the DOM stuff won't be set as that's only done in the first `if`.

Comment: @NigelRen ops i didn't checked it carefully... i re-edited my answer. Now check this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this to one condition, this saves having to hard code all of the different authors/editors.

First check if the author is set, then include this value in the XPath expressions...

```
if ( !empty($_GET['author'])) {
    $getMj = new DOMDocument();
    $getMj->load("Margret-Jane.xml");
    $mjxpath = new DOMXpath($getMj);

    $mjAuth = $mjxpath->query("//author[@id = '{$_GET['author']}']")->length;
    $mjEdit = $mjxpath->query("//editor[@id = '{$_GET['author']}']")->length;
    $mjResult = ($mjAuth + $mjEdit);
    echo $mjResult;
}
```